# Is there a better way to write this code, to automate and convert these strings into integers and store them as integers in python

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion, integer

I want to convert all the strings in the list 'a' to integers and save them in a separate list with each string as list. The code written works but the automation of this code is not good, Is there a better way to write this code.

```
a = ['1 2 3 4','4 3 2','8 6 4 3']
lis = []
lis1 = []
lis2 = []
for i in a:
    if i == a[0]:
        for k in range(0,len(i),2):
            lis.append(int(i[k]))
    if i == a[1]:
        for k in range(0,len(i),2):
            lis1.append(int(i[k]))
    if i == a[2]:
        for k in range(0,len(i),2):
            lis2.append(int(i[k]))

final_list = [lis, lis1, lis2]  
print(final_list)
```

Comment: What is "not good" about this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
a = ["1 2 3 4", "4 3 2", "8 6 4 3"]
final_list = [list(map(int, s.split())) for s in a]
print(final_list)
```

Prints:

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2], [8, 6, 4, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over list `a`, each loop get elements of *string(inner-list)* separated by a space and converted them all to `int`:

```py
a = ["1 2 3 4", "4 3 2", "8 6 4 3"]
res = []
for l in a:
    res+=[[int(elments) for elments in l.split(' ')]]

print(res) #[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2], [8, 6, 4, 3]]
```